# Translating OMI(AURA) HDF5 To GeoTIFF?

Tags: python-2.7

I have omi (aura satellite) level 2 data sets for the aerosol product in he5 file format. Now I want to read that he5 file and save it as geotiff format in python. Could you help me anyone regarding this issue?